# how to use Flow with external Higher Order Component Wrapper

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, flowtype

[Flow documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/) only shows how to declare a custom Higher Order Component to work with custom Class and its Props. In my case I have a custom Class like:

```
type Props = {
  navigation: Object,
  isFocused: boolean
}

type State = {
  config: AppConfig,
  pack: Package,
  init: boolean,
}

class MainAppScreen extends React.Component<Props, State> {
...
}
export default withNavigationFocus(MainAppScreen);
```

and want to wrap it with external HOC from 'react-navigation';

What should I do (beside //$FlowFixMe) to get rid of this message:

Error:(111, 16) Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Cannot determine the type of this call expression. Please provide an annotation, e.g., by adding a type cast around this expression. (`signature-verification-failure`)

Thanks.

UPDATE:
As @user11307804 pointed into the right direction, I have been also trying involving flow-typs for external libraries. However it still seems not to be possible to import a type for a (HOC) function like:

```
  declare export function withNavigationFocus<Props: {...}, ComponentType: React$ComponentType<Props>>(
    Component: ComponentType
  ): React$ComponentType<$Diff<React$ElementConfig<ComponentType>, {| isFocused: ?boolean |}>>;
```

When I try to import it like: ([following this example](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/wiki/Importing-And-Using-Type-Definitions))

```
import type {withNavigationFocus} from 'react-navigation';
```

I get the error:

```
Error:(22, 14) Cannot import the value `withNavigationFocus` as a type. `import type` only works on type exports like type aliases, interfaces, and classes. If you intended to import the type of a value use `import typeof` instead.
```

and if I try with typeof I get:

```
import typeof {withNavigationFocus} from 'react-navigation';
```

I get the errors:

```
Error:(22, 16) Cannot declare  `withNavigationFocus` [1] because the name is already bound.
Error:(112, 16) Cannot call `withNavigationFocus` because  Named import from module `react-navigation` [1] is not a function.
Error:(112, 16) Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Cannot determine the type of this call expression. Please provide an annotation, e.g., by adding a type cast around this expression. (`signature-verification-failure`)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `withNavigationFocus`?

Comment: I can not tell, the API Reference is not very specific about it: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html

Comment: Your code examples for “When I try to import it like” and “if I try with typeof” are identical; they both have `typeof` in them. Is that just a copy-paste error, or did you forget to try `import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';`?

Comment: Also note that you are trying to import `withNavigationFocus`, but the `declare` statement you quoted earlier is for `withNavigation`, a different function. `withNavigationFocus` [does have a type declaration](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/1182cc56c8471c85190c28f3542f0f58d080853f/definitions/npm/react-navigation_v4.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/react-navigation_v4.x.x.js#L940-L942) though.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane good observation, It was just copy and waste here. I'll update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flow is complaining that `withNavigationFocused` is untyped. Fortunately, the `flow-typed` project has [`react-navigation` types](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-navigation_v4.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/react-navigation_v4.x.x.js). (There are other definition files for different version of `react-navigation` or `flow`; the one I've linked is for `react-navigation^4.0.0` and `flow^0.114.0`.) You can include the library definition in your project following the [Library Definitions documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) (essentially, just save the file in `<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed` directory).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the missing link.

Comment: Actually it looked like the right solution, but it seams not to work for HOC functions, I updated the question, maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: Not sure where the best place to put this update is... In any case, you don't need to need to import the type `withNavigationFocus`. Flow will automatically know to look at the `declare type withNavigationFocus` because the `declare module 'react-navigation'` line corresponds to the import statement `import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation'`.